# Прокручивание поля в конец TextBox при выводе в TextBox содержания консоли

Tags: c#, winforms

С помощью решения в этом вопросе: [Redirecting Console.WriteLine() to Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726852/redirecting-console-writeline-to-textbox)
был реализован вывод текста в TextBox. В свойствах проставлено только чтение и т.п. Но, при работе программы и выводе содержимого консоли в текстовое поле, поле автоматически прокручивается в самый верх (тогда как новые строки появляются снизу). В свойствах ничего связанного с этим не нашел. Можно ли каким либо образом "автоматически" прокручивать видимую часть поля до последней выведенной строки?

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Используется WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После каждого добавления текста

```
TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength;
TextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```